# Query a data view of a child business unit from the parent

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible to query the data view (_Job) of a child Business Unit from the parent Business Unit?

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM C1234567._Job
```

Where 1234567 is the MID of the child BU.

Answer (score 4):

According to SFMC Support, you cannot query a Child BU from the Parent, but you can query the Parent from the Child.

```
SELECT * FROM _Job --This is for the child BU when the query is run in the child BU Account.
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM ENT._Job --This is for the Parent BU when the query is run in the child BU Account.
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont believe this is possible. _Job is the only view which doesn't contain data for the enterprise at admin level (very annoying when all the rest do).

Unfortunately you'll need to create a shared DE and query data from each BUs _Job into that DE.