# Retrieve the subscribers from each business unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, subscriber, hierarchy, client-id

Starting from the All Subscribers list of the parent business unit, I'm trying to know which subscribers are being part of each child business unit.

As it is not defined any Subscriber Filter, how can I figure it out? Is there a way to get the MID of each subscriber (like the ClientID)?

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the answer here:

[Query a data view of a child business unit from the parent](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161190/query-a-data-view-of-a-child-business-unit-from-the-parent)

> According to SFMC Support, you cannot query a Child BU from the Parent, but you can query the Parent from the Child.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also tried that but it doesn't solve my need because with that query I will retrieve the entire list of subscribers from the parent one. I only want to retrieve the subscribers that are part of each child business unit.

Comment: There is another way mentioned in that page, that is not an ideal practice but you might want to follow it. You can create a DE in Child and share it with Parent and then automate a query in Child to retrieve data hourly/daily on that DE. At least you can have the results in Parent.

Answer (score 1):

I finally Defined a Subscriber Filter based on one of the Profile Attributes that can be used to differentiate the subscriber per each Child BU, for example, the Country field.