# Allow simultaneous writes to the same Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

I have a use case where I need to bring `_PushAddress` data from 60 Business Units back to the Global Business Unit.

For information `_PushAddress` has a restricted view of data available in a single Business Unit. Therefore It should be queried at each Business Unit in order to have the full picture of MobilePush data.

For that, I am running multiple queries that upsert `_PushAddress` data to a Shared Data Extension.

The queries fall in error (probably a deadlock) when I run them at the same time whereas I have no issue when I run them with a 5 minute interval.

I was wondering how I can still run them at the same time and have no issue.

Comment: Instead using write to the global (shared) dataextension, can't you just use one sql query that reads from multiple sources at once, within one query?

Comment: The only source is `_PushAddress` but I have to run the query in the Context of each business unit to have access to its data.

Comment: Yeah you are right, just thought that this could be possible. Unfortunately it is not like shown [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161190/query-a-data-view-of-a-child-business-unit-from-the-parent)

Comment: You're right. `_PushAddress` and  `_Job` have the same behavior.

Comment: Why not run one query, then the others right after as updates to the same data extension in an automation? Pretty sure there is no way to write simultaneously to one DE.

Comment: There is no way I can run these queries in the same automation because I have to execute them in each Business Unit. The only solution I have is to put an interval (5 minutes for e.g) between each Automation. But this solution doesn't prevent from a possible deadlock.

Comment: You cannot do that @garek007 because he is in 60 different BUs that do not share one automation studio (as far as i know). I believe that this is a situation where you have to begin to use APIs. Establish Connections to every child BU via ClientID and ClientSecret and get the values via SOAP/SSJS and store them into the GlobalBusinessUnit. Otherwise you cannot get a solution that sits in one place and takes care of the timings. I would create SSJS activities inside the main BU. (But i am not confident with API integration until now, but i will try to improve) I believe WSProxy is the solution.

Comment: Oops, I missed that part.... I think you are right.

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick I was hoping that a possible SQL hint would prevent me from using WSProxy from the Global Business Unit but I guess that I have no choice... I will wait for a possible solution from a SFMC god.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few snippets on WSProxy that can be used inside a SSJS activity that should help get you towards your solution without requiring you to build multiple automations in all your BUs and remove the 'house of cards' effect this would have.

First you need to create the data extension inside the parent account that you want all this data stored in. You then need to share it across each of your BUs.

Then you need to create a rowset or JSON to hold all your BUs. If they are stored inside of a DE, you can do a SSJS Retrieve on the DE or a LookupRows. Or, as I will use in my example, build it as a JSON inside your script:

`var midJson = '[{MID:12345},{MID:23456},{MID:43234},....]`

You then would need to create a SSJS FOR LOOP based off of the `midJson` rowset/JSON you just gathered.

`for (var i=0; i < midJson.length; i++) { }`

Inside of this, you would then need to gather the MID for each row:

`var mid = midJson[i].MID;`

If you already have the query built, (I would recommend an easy naming convention for customerkey and name. Like perhaps `{{MID}}_PushAddressQuery`)

so you can then set your query CustomerKey in the FOR loop:

`var queryCustKey = MID + '_PushAddressQuery'`

you then would run the query using WSProxy(): (I added in a try/catch for error handling)

```
    try {

        var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

        api.setClientId({ "ID": MID }); //Impersonates the BU
        var action = "Start";
        var props = {
                CustomerKey: queryCustKey
        };
        var opts = {};

        var data = api.performItem("QueryDefinition", props, action, opts);
   } catch(e) {
        Platform.Response.Write('error: ' + Platform.Function.Stringify(e));
   }
```

as a safety measure you can then use another WSProxy API call to check the status of the query and not let it move on until the status is back to Active again.

```
    do {

         var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

         prox.setClientId({ "ID": mid }); //Impersonates the BU

         var cols = ["Status"];
         var filter = {
             Property: "TaskID",
             SimpleOperator: "equals",
             Value: taskid
         };

         var desc = prox.retrieve("AsyncActivityStatus", cols, filter);

         var queryStatus = desc.Results[0].Status;

     } while(queryStatus != 'Completed')
```

you have then complete the current iterate of this for loop and move to the next.

You also are able to create/edit the query inside of WSProxy() if you wanted to. See below for example on creating a new QueryDefinition:

```
var proxy = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

/* proxy.setClientId({ "ID": MID }); */ //Impersonates the BU
api.resetClientIds();  //Resets the MID to the parent as AsyncActivity is on parent BU, not on Child BU

var queryCustKey = MID + '_PushAddressQuery';
var name = MID + '_PushAddressQuery';

var queryObj = {
    Name: name,
    CustomerKey: queryCustKey,
    Description: "PushAddressQuery",
    QueryText: "SELECT * FROM [...]",
    TargetType: "DE",
    DataExtensionTarget: [{
        CustomerKey: "myTargetDEKey",
        Name: "myTargetDEName"
    }],
    TargetUpdateType: "Update"
}

var result = proxy.createItem("QueryDefinition", queryObj);
```

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to @zeljazouli for the solution on query status using AsyncActivityStatus object to retrieve the Query's run status as the 'Status' inside the QueryDefinition object is not related to the running of the query.

Comment: Thank you for providing this complete answer. This is exactly how I imagined the solution in the first place but I was not keen on adding a do while loop that will check for the status of each query. I will try this code and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: As a note, I found that sometimes the Perform requires you to use the ObjectID of the Query or it can throw an error.  It might be worth doing a retrieve script to get all the MID and ObjectID and place in either a JSON or DE for easy access.

Comment: I tried many times to get the status of the Query from the QueryDefinition object but I always get 'Active' in the response. I managed to get it using AsyncActivityStatus object by passing 'Task ID' but It only works in the Parent BU. I get an empty Results array for chid BU queries. Here is a pastebin for the script : https://pastebin.com/Tep7naes. Response for AsyncActivityStatus (Child BU) : https://pastebin.com/0qKKbzHB . Response for AsyncActivityStatus (Parent BU) https://pastebin.com/rkk3GvwK

Comment: Good catch @zeljazouli and good solution for the status issue. It definitely sounds like the issue is that it is not finding the Async activity for the Child BU.  The impersonation SHOULD run it at the local level, but try removing the impersonation for the Async retrieve. perhaps it is running a child activity from the parent BU (somehow) so the activity is on parent BU, even though the target is a child. (It is MC so stranger things have happened.) Try using `api.resetClientIds();` instead of the impersonation function or switch MID value to parent for that WSProxy call.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think you made a mistake while updating your comment : api.resetClientIds() should go inside the do..while loop that retrieves the AsyncActivityStatus. But even with that I still receive an empty response. Which means that the parent BU doesn't find the Task Id because it belongs to the child BU.

Comment: Honestly, I am at a loss, AsyncActivityStatus is not really that well documented, so it could be something as simple as using `ParentTaskID` or similar...I would recommend contacting SFMC support about it as they have next to no documentation on it, so it cannot be expected that you can solve this on your own. I will try to reach out on my end as well and see what I get back.

Comment: here is the best 'documentation' on it I have found: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_the_status_of_programs_using_asyncactivitystatus.htm

Comment: Thank you. I will ask SFMC support and hopefully find a solution. I will let you know.

Comment: WSProxy does not work correctly retrieving 'AsyncActivityStatus' object. What you need to do is create an installed package and use SOAP / XML. Make sure that you request an oAuth token for the target BU in question, and then in the soap payload specify the same target BU in clientId attribute.  Honestly, its very annoying that WSproxy wont work for this object and we have to use raw XML and request a token.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have implemented :

1 - Create a staging DE for each BU in shared folder

2 - Create an automation/query in each child BU that upsert PushAddress data to the related DE. These automations are scheduled to run at 3 a.m

3 - Create 60 queries in Parent BU that upserts data from each staging DE to the final DE

4 - Create an automation in Parent BU with 60 steps to run all the queries sequentially. This automation is scheduled to run at 3:30 a.m

This solution runs all the queries in Child Business Unit at the same time and prevents deadlocks from happening by combining all the records in the final DE in a sequential mode.

You can post a comment if you have any improvement.

Comment: This seems a bit unsustainable. Especially as Business units get added or removed. Plus you run into a higher risk of error due to a significant number of moving parts, essentially creating a house of cards. I would instead recommend using an API call inside of a FOR loop to run your query in each BU aimed at a shared DE. This would keep it sequential without locking and is easy to update and maintain.

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington for your comment. That is exactly what I wanted to do in the first place but automations run in Async mode which means that I will have to check the status of each automation before launching the next one in the for loop. I think It will be time and ressource consuming. What do you think ?

Comment: You would have all this automated inside of a single Script Activity in the parent account. You could even automate the Script to include the Query creation/edit itself inside the Script Activity so you do not even need to build it out prior to utilizing the script.  You would utilize WSProxy and its Impersonation ability to target each of your BU inside the SSJS FOR LOOP. (WSProxy Impersonation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_impersonate.htm)

Comment: I get you. How am I going to schedule my automations if they run in Async mode ? I have to wait until automation in BU 1 is over to run automation 2 in BU 2.

Comment: You aren't using but 1 automation. The script in this automation will iterate and run through each query using the for loop. No other automations are needed.